# Всем здравствуйте. Мне нужна помощь с отступами header в html

Tags: html

Мне надо, чтобы блоки "Наши страницы", "Приложение для телефона" и "О нас" были на одном уровне с заголовком. Буду очень благодарен.

```css
header {
    border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(28, 233, 158), rgb(37, 224, 224));
    border-image-slice: 1;
}
.weare {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: right;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(28, 233, 158), rgb(37, 224, 224));
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}
.pages, .apps, .aboutus {
    margin-right: 10%;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.Name {
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    background-clip: text;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgb(28, 233, 158), rgb(37, 224, 224));
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
    font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="header.css">
            <meta charset="utf-8">
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <h1 class="Name">Диваны</h1>
                <div class="weare">
                    <div class="pages">Наши страницы</div>
                    <div class="apps">Приложение для телефона</div>
                    <div class="aboutus">О нас</div>
                </div>
            </header>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Переместить `h1` внутрь `div class="weare"`?

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.